# How to run Lift's 'Ecommerce example' app

Tags: scala, sbt, lift

I'm new to Scala and Lift and SBT. I've cloned [Ecommerce example](https://github.com/hedleyproctor/amur-lift-ecommerce-example) from `Lift`'s [sample applications](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Sample_Applications).

Now I want to simply run the application.

[Documentation says](http://cookbook.liftweb.net/#_for_windows), that `container:start` should start the app. But I'm getting error:

```
> container:start    
[error] No action named 'container:start' exists.
[info] Execute 'help' for a list of commands or 'actions' for a list of available project actions and methods.
[info]
[info] Total time: 0 s, completed 25.05.2013 16:47:05
```

I guess that maybe it's because version difference.

```
[info]    using LiftProject with sbt 0.7.5 and Scala 2.7.7
```

How can I start this application ? 
And if it's caused by version difference is it possible to upgrade the application to latest sbt and scala version ?

**Update**
I've tried to use `jetty-start` and received another error:

```
> jetty-start
[error] No action named 'jetty-start' exists.
[info] Execute 'help' for a list of commands or 'actions' for a list of available project actions and methods.
```

I've also found another similar command `jetty-run` from sbt `help`. When I run it I'm getting a huge number of compilation errors. It seems like my scala 2.9.2 cannot compile the code.

Answer (score 0):

This project, as far as I see, uses the old SBT version. The old way to start the web application is:

```
./sbt
> jetty-start
```

if you want to reload the app on source change, use `~ jetty-start`

Note that there's a far more up to date liftweb project example here: https://github.com/lift/lift_25_sbt

Answer (score 0):

probably sbt did not download the requried jar files.

run the following command

```
> sbt 
> update
```

now sbt should download the requried jar files

```
>jetty-run
```

now sbt should compile and run the web-app.